# Why rectangle's radius gets ignored in this situation?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a `Xamarin.Forms (v5.0.0.2515)` project.

I have encountered this strange behavior using this scenario:

1. I have a view with 5 rectangles. `RadiusX/RadiusY` for each rectangle is `20`.
2. I assign this view to a `ContentView` and everything looks normal (Fig. 1)
3. I assign another view to the `ContentView`
4. I assign back the view to the `ContentView` and rounded borders are gone (Fig. 2)

What can cause this issue?

This is a sample code to reproduce the issue.

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App
{
    public class SamplePage : ContentPage
    {
        public SamplePage()
        {
            var grid = new Grid
            {
                RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection
                {
                    new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
                    new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Star }
                }
            };

            var btn = new Button { Text = "Replace the view!" };
            Grid.SetRow(btn, 0);
            grid.Children.Add(btn);

            var rect = new Xamarin.Forms.Shapes.Rectangle
            {
                RadiusX = 20,
                RadiusY = 20,
                Fill = Brush.Azure,
                StrokeThickness = 3,
                Stroke = Brush.Black
            };

            var cv = new ContentView { Content = rect };
            Grid.SetRow(cv, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(cv);

            btn.Clicked += (_, __) =>
            {
                cv.Content = new Label();
                cv.Content = rect;
            };

            Content = grid;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

| Fig. 1 | Fig. 2 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Normal] | [image: Abnormal] |

Comment: instead of *describing* the code, please *post* the code

Comment: @Jason Thanks for your comment. Please check out the new edit.

Comment: please read [ask].  Posting code as links to external repos is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

According to your demo you provided, I found that the code `cv.Content = new Label();` caused the problem. I changed the demo and you can check.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            var grid = new Grid
            {
                RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection
                {
                    new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto },
                    new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Star }
                }
            };

            var btn = new Button { Text = "Replace the view!" };
            Grid.SetRow(btn, 0);
            grid.Children.Add(btn);

            var rect = new Xamarin.Forms.Shapes.Rectangle
            {
                RadiusX = 50,
                RadiusY = 10,
                Fill = Brush.Azure,
                StrokeThickness = 10,
                Stroke = Brush.Black
            };

            var rect2 = new Xamarin.Forms.Shapes.Rectangle
            {
                RadiusX = 20,
                RadiusY = 20,
                Fill = Brush.Azure,
                StrokeThickness = 3,
                Stroke = Brush.Black
            };

            var cv = new ContentView {Content = rect2};
            Grid.SetRow(cv, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(cv);

            btn.Clicked += (_,__) =>
            {
              
                cv.Content = rect;
            };

            Content = grid;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the whole point of the issue. When the `ContentView`'s `Content` is set with something else and then is set back to the `Rectangle` the borders are not round anymore.

Comment: @Hadi Fooladi Talari If you think this is a good answer you can mark it as a solution and other people can refer to it. Thanks.